# "Here is the invoice for January"

Tags: english-to-german

I work for a client month-based. I send an invoice at the beginning of e.g. February and write:

"Here is the invoice for January"

(Also like "please find the invoice attached" but less formal)

What is correct: "Anbei die Rechnung vom Januar"? "Anbei die Rechnung für Januar"? Or something else?

Comment: Both are okay. *Vom Januar* suggests it's an old invoice you resend. It's the invoice "from January", not "for January". Same as in English.

Answer (score 4):

Both is ok, but note two things:

1. *"Here is"* is not *»anbei«*. *"Here is"* is *»hier ist«* (which sounds a little bit boring in German) and *»anbei«* is *"enclosed"*.
2. If you use *für* I also would add an article. (There already is an article contained in *vom = von dem*)

So this are versions you can use (in Germany and Switzerland:

> Anbei die Rechnung vom Januar
>   Enclosed the invoice from January
>
> Anbei die Rechnung für den Januar
>   Enclosed the invoice for January

If your customer lives in Austria, you have to know that the first month of the year has a different name in Austria. It is *Jänner*. So in Austria you better use this:

> Anbei die Rechnung vom Jänner
>   Anbei die Rechnung für den Jänner

*Januar* will be understood in Austria too, but you can make your Austrian customers happy, if you use the name they use.

If you want to avoid complications with the month's name, write:

> Anbei die Rechnung von 01/2017
>   Anbei die Rechnung für 01/2017

Note, that now you don't use an article, which turns *vom* (*von dem*) into *von*.

---

**Difference between *von* and *für***

- **Die Rechnung für den Jänner/Januar**
  This means: The invoice contains items for the month January, i.e. it covers goods and services, that the customer consumed in this month. The date of the invoice's items is in January.
- **Die Rechnung vom Jänner/Januar**
  This means: The invoice was written in January. The date in the header of the invoice is a date in January.

---

### Addendum

<sup>*(Thank you, user unknown for your [comment](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/39019/here-is-the-invoice-for-january/39024#comment96264_39024))*</sup>

You also can write:

> Anbei die Jännerrechnung (A)
>   Anbei die Januarrechnung (D, CH)

This is

> Enclosed the January invoice

*»Januarrechnung«* and *»Jännerrechnung«* are compound nouns, built from the month's name and the word »Rechnung«. In German as well as in English here it is unclear, if it is the invoice *from* or *for* January.

Comment: Nicht zu vergessen, die Januarrechnung.